# Install anaconda packages for local python version

Tags: python, anaconda

I am setting up an anaconda environment, and I'm able to install and run all packages against the default anaconda python except for a package installed on the local system.

On the other hand, I have a locally compiled python executable that works with the problematic package, however when I run it explicitly, it can't see the packages I installed for the anaconda version of py (as expected). Is there a way to install packages against my local executable of python?

The error I'm receiving is

```
ImportError: /data/..../libboost_python-mt.so.1.55.0: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromEncodedObject
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by symlinking my system's python executable in the anaconda folder and installing packages against it. Still, it's a dirty fix and I had some problems with packages that worked with the default python executable.